# Finding the Min/Max value within a Struct

Tags: c, struct

So I've opened a CSV file, and added it to a struct. I want to find the highest/lowest value in the third column and the highest/lowest value in the fourth column. Then printing out each row where they occur.

```
typedef struct {
    float xvalue;
    float yvalue;
    float uvalue;
    float vvalue;
} flow_data;
```

Here is adding the CSV file -

```
int total = 0;
flow_data d;
flow_data* dataset = NULL;

while(4 == fscanf(fp, "%f, %f, %f, %f\n", &d.xvalue, &d.yvalue, &d.uvalue, &d.vvalue))
{
    dataset = realloc(dataset, sizeof(*dataset) * (total + 1));
    dataset[total] = d;
    total++;
}
```

And the operation, I'm aware that it's a ridiculous way of doing things but I'm not sure how to make it more efficient. How would I add everything into a function? Can you pass entire Structs into a function?

```
float minvalueu = 100000, maxvalueu = 0;
float minvaluev = 100000, maxvaluev = 0;
int ivalueofminu = 0, ivalueofmaxu = 0;
int ivalueofminv = 0, ivalueofmaxv = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    flow_data* p = &dataset[i];

    if ( p->uvalue > maxvalueu)
    {
        maxvalueu = p->uvalue;
        ivalueofmaxu = i;
    }

    if ( p->uvalue < minvalueu)
    {
        minvalueu = p->uvalue;
        ivalueofminu = i;
    }

    if ( p->vvalue > maxvaluev)
    {
        maxvaluev = p->vvalue;
        ivalueofmaxv = i;
    }

    if ( p->vvalue < minvaluev)
    {
        minvaluev = p->uvalue;
        ivalueofminv = i;
    }

    printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", p->xvalue, p->yvalue, p->vvalue, p->uvalue);
}

flow_data* z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxu];
printf("Max of U - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
printf("Min of U - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxv];
printf("Max of V - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
printf("Min of V - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass a struct to a function, but in your case it's most likely more efficient to pass a _pointer_ to your struct to the function instead of the whole struct. And your algorithm isn't specially inefficient, it's the most straightforward way.

Comment: It would be safer to initialize the min and max values from the first struct, e.g. `float minvalueu = dataset[0].uvalue;`. And then start the `for` loop at `i = 1`.

Comment: How do you manage duplicate ? if "uminvalue" is on index 3 and 5, what is the expected result ?

Comment: I had not thought of that actually but the nature of the data there won't be any duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire code in the final code block of the question can be moved to a function.
The parameters of the function would be the pointer to the structure `flow_data` and the number of elements in the array (`total`).
The function would look something like this:

```
void findAndPrintMaxMinVals(flow_data* dataset, int total)
```

called from `main()`

```
findAndPrintMaxMinVals(dataset, total)
```

Complete Code Below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    float xvalue;
    float yvalue;
    float uvalue;
    float vvalue;
} flow_data;

void findAndPrintMaxMinVals(flow_data* dataset, int total)
{
    float minvalueu = 100000, maxvalueu = 0;
    float minvaluev = 100000, maxvaluev = 0;
    int ivalueofminu = 0, ivalueofmaxu = 0;
    int ivalueofminv = 0, ivalueofmaxv = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        flow_data* p = &dataset[i];

        if ( p->uvalue > maxvalueu)
        {
            maxvalueu = p->uvalue;
            ivalueofmaxu = i;
        }

        if ( p->uvalue < minvalueu)
        {
            minvalueu = p->uvalue;
            ivalueofminu = i;
        }

        if ( p->vvalue > maxvaluev)
        {
            maxvaluev = p->vvalue;
            ivalueofmaxv = i;
        }

        if ( p->vvalue < minvaluev)
        {
            minvaluev = p->uvalue;
            ivalueofminv = i;
        }

        printf("%.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", p->xvalue, p->yvalue, p->vvalue, p->uvalue);
    }

    flow_data* z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxu];
    printf("Max of U - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

    z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
    printf("Min of U - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

    z = &dataset[ivalueofmaxv];
    printf("Max of V - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);

    z = &dataset[ivalueofminu];
    printf("Min of V - %.7f, %.7f, %.7f, %.7f\n", z->xvalue, z->yvalue, z->vvalue, z->uvalue);  
}


int main() {    

    int total = 4; //total no of datasets for example
    int i;
    flow_data d;
    flow_data* dataset = NULL;

    dataset = (flow_data*)malloc(sizeof(flow_data) * total); //memory for 4 elements for testing

    //Generate values and fill in
    for(i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        dataset[i].xvalue = (i+1) * 7;
        dataset[i].yvalue = (i+1) * 8;
        dataset[i].uvalue = (i+1) * 9;
        dataset[i].vvalue = (i+1) * 10;
    }   
    findAndPrintMaxMinVals(dataset, total); 
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the error error: too many arguments to function 'maxveldiff'

Comment: This means the number of arguments you are passing to the function is greater than the number of parameters in the function definition. Are you doing what I suggested in the answer? What is 'maxveldiff'?

Comment: I just renamed the function. Copied what you said exactly

Comment: I tested it out before posting this answer. It should work.

Comment: I think because I have the function in a different file using a header function, previously in the header file it was this - void maxveldiff(const char* flow_file); what do you think it should be now

Comment: This function takes only one parameter, that's why the compiler give that particular error. Can't you use a different name for this function?

Comment: Yeah the name doesn't matter, when I change it to void findAndPrintMaxMinVals(flow_data* dataset, int total) within the header, it tells me that flow_data is an unknown type name. So I'm not sure what I should put in there instead.

Comment: Is the flow_data structure defined in the same file as this function?

Comment: So it's working, just that it only works for maxvalueu for some reason, can you just post your code? I don't want to bother you too much

Comment: @tobytobias:  Posted it. Try it in this pattern

Comment: Yeah it's not working, other then showing you the entire code I think I'll just have to play around with it.